# Problem with mobile redirection login

Tags: 7, theming

I've implemented this mobile redirection logic but for the past 10 days I've been getting weird behavior(with www version, mobile data is shown sometimes).

**Here is Mobile Theme return logic**

Also I find different behavior if I uncomment "**return 'bartik'** in the last line below.

```
  function mobile_detect_custom_theme() {

        if (strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 2), "m.") == 0)
        {
            return 'mobile_theme';
        }

//return 'bartik'; //IF I uncomment it I find different behavior
    }
```

**In Hook_book I've setup this redirection logic:**

```
//wantdesktop is set if user has specifically selected Desktop version
if (@$_COOKIE['wantdesktop'] == 'true') {
        if (strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 2), "m.") == 0) {

            $url = "http://www.example.com/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, 302);
            exit(0);
        }

        return;
    }



//wantmobile is set if user has specifically selected mobile version
      if (@$_COOKIE['wantmobile'] == 'true') {
        if (strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 2), "m.") != 0) {

            $url = "http://m.example.com/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];



            header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, 302);

            exit(0);
        }

        return;
    }



//BROWSER DETECTION LOGIC HERE which fills $browser['ismobiledevice'] with true/false


    if ( $browser['ismobiledevice'] == 'true') {
        //check the current domain
        if (strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 2), "m.") != 0) { //not a mobile url
            $url = "http://m.example.com/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, 302);
            exit(0);

        }
    } else { //desktop
        if (strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 2), "m.") == 0) { //is a mobile url

            $url = "http://www.example.com/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            header('Location: ' . $url, TRUE, 302);
            exit(0);

        }
    }
```

**What is wrong with this logic?**

Comment: Are you sure your code truly detects the device? If yes, then what is its behavior when you visit it by desktop browser and mobile browser?

Comment: I see mobile version on www. URL sometimes.

Comment: how do you set cookies? Please add code.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest an alternative approach of using the [Themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module. It was built to solve the exact issue you are facing:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional properties exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:
>
> - individually-styled channels
> - a front-page / "splash" screen
> - a date/time-selected Christmas theme
> - mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
> - special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> - content, user, or role -specific themes
> - indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
> - testing your redesign safely on a live server

The important thing to note about Themekey, is that the module works well with the external caching as well. Do check out its [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2135427) for more.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I found is

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Because, As an example, If the url is `www.example.com/test` the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `/test` not `test` so your code should be

```
$url = "http://www.example.com" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and also replace `example.com` with this:

```
global $base_url;
$url =  $base_url.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and use `$base_url` to check for the `m.example.com` (whether it is the mobile version or not)

Comment: I also need answer for  different behavior if I uncomment "return 'bartik' in the last line of first function.

Comment: If you uncomment the return bartik, when does it show different behavior? by desktop or mobile?

Comment: on Desktop it does not seem to work properly when commented on Desktop browsers

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use simple this module [Simple Mobile Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_mobile_redirect) ? It has good interface for all of your mobile redirection tasks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

And as a third alternative, [Mobile Switch](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_switch)

Answer (score 0):

So in answer to the 'bartik' bit,

> 'HTTP_HOST' Contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

so this code

```
enter code here

function mobile_detect_custom_theme() {

    if (strcasecmp(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 2), "m.") == 0)
    {
        return 'mobile_theme';
    }

   return 'bartik'; //IF I uncomment it I find different behavior
}
```

means that your if must be returning false, and then you get bartik back

HOST headers are mandatory for [http 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4%5D) , but in http 1.0 they are optional .

do you have any proxies - these can often introduce headers, or rewrite headers.

try using the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable, its generally safer (doesnt come from the client, it comes from the virtual host configuration instead).